# how do I place an absolutely positioned image outside its parent element which has overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble making sure my active graphic is positioned outside of the button, basically the overflow of the parent element keeps the graphic hidden inside of it instead of being outside. I have tried to use position:absolute and z-index but I cant solve this.

HTML

```
<ul id="mynav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul id="subernav">
            <li><a href="#">Inner Link 1</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Inner Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inner Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="active ir">Active Link</span>
    </li>
    <!-- More links -->
    <!--<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>-->
    <!--<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>-->
    <!--<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>-->
    <!--<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>-->
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
body{background:#000;color:#000;font-family:Arial;padding:20px;}
a{text-decoration:none;color:#000;}

#mynav > li{height:45px;background:#fff;width:458px;padding:5px 10px;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:30px;position:relative}

#mynav > li a{line-height:45px;}

#mynav li.active:hover{height:90px;cursor:pointer}


#mynav li .active{background:#f00 url('http://dummyimage.com/15/f00/fff&text=+') no-repeat -668px -214px;width:15px;height:15px;position:absolute;left:50%;bottom:-15px;margin-left:-7.5px;border:1px solid #f00;z-index:250}

#subernav li{display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;}
#subernav li a{color:#f00;}

.ir{display:block;text-indent:-999em;overflow:hidden;background-repeat:no-repeat;text-align:left;direction:ltr;}​
```

Link to fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/UbvQk/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `overflow: hidden` and the `height` from the `mynav active` (and the `:hover`).

Set the `subernav` to `display:none;`.

Add `#mynav li.active:hover #subernav` to have `display:block;`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UbvQk/7/)